# Which are considered not-for-public fields of the ones returned by getaddressinfo?

Tags: address, private-key, privacy

Create a new address in a descriptor wallet, then `getaddressinfo` - a result like the following is output:

```
{
  "result": {
    "address": "bc1qf...",
    "scriptPubKey": "00144f...",
    "ismine": true,
    "solvable": true,
    "desc": "wpkh([5ba92dac/84'/0'/0'/0/0]0321c...)#cp9v54cz",
    "parent_desc": "wpkh([5ba92dac/84'/0'/0']xpub.../0/*)#9udarq7y",
    "iswatchonly": false,
    "isscript": false,
    "iswitness": true,
    "witness_version": 0,
    "witness_program": "...",
    "pubkey": "...",
    "ischange": false,
    "timestamp": 1679913806,
    "hdkeypath": "m/84'/0'/0'/0/0",
    "hdseedid": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "hdmasterfingerprint": "...",
    "labels": [
      ""
    ]
  },
  "error": null,
  "id": "getaddressinfo"
}
```

Which of all these fields are considered safe if accessed by the public, and which are not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a security perspective (i.e. could directly lead to loss of funds) the only thing you should be worried about are private keys or seeds that are used to generate private keys. There are no private keys or seeds in this output.

From a privacy perspective it is all data that isn't required to be public so you wouldn't choose to make it public. But if it was all leaked it wouldn't be a disaster and lead to loss of funds. Some fields (e.g. the address) are already public on the blockchain and others (e.g. part of the descriptor) is made public on the blockchain when you spend from the address.